# Webpage doesn't display images from Cloudfront?

Tags: html, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a strange issue on my site where I am able to browse to an image, however I can't get it to display using HTML.

HTML as follows:

```
<img src="http://cdn.jackpallot.me/files/_header/14ae39ea5fb211e28b4622000a9e2975_7.jpg﻿" width="845﻿" height="250﻿" class="header-img">
```

The actual image can be viewed at http://cdn.jackpallot.me/files/_header/14ae39ea5fb211e28b4622000a9e2975_7.jpg and loads as expected.

I am guessing this is a Cloudfront setting, although I haven't come across anything that seems to be causing it.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: This is Cloudfront related, it's possibly a setting ive missed because the image works fine using the S3 URL.

Comment: Odd. First time I loaded the image, I got access denied. The second and all subsequent loads I didn't. I wonder if it's something to do with whether or not my edge node has it cached.

Comment: Is it possible that you tried to download it before you originally uploaded it, causing Cloudfront to cache the 403 access denied/no such key page?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this wasn't Cloudfront related at all. It was a strange issue where extra characters were being added to the end of the URL. Sublime Text didn't spot them, but another program did. Thanks anyway!